# how to iterate using jstl code

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

This is my code

```
<c:set var="radioCount" scope="session" value="${radiocount}"/>
```

I want to create a table with no of rows equal to radiocount so trying to use the below expression but getting an error

```
<c:forEach   begin='1' end='radioCount'> 
            <tr>
            <td>
            <input style='width:500px' type='text' / >
            </td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

Comment: /jsp/showUserDefQuesPage.jsp(63,33) quote symbol expected if i dont use quotes

Comment: else For input string: "radioCount"
 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use bracktes in your `forEach` and use double quote `"` instead of `'` in your code:

```
  <c:forEach   begin="1" end="${radioCount}">
```